How to make CSS transform-origin scaling and translate work well together?
I am trying to make a canvas element that I can drag around and scale. I have a html range input element that handles the zooming.
I am having issues with getting the zooming and the translating to work well together. When I zoom, I change the transform-origin to the last position the mouse was when dragging, making it zoom while focusing on a point that should be relatively close to the middle of the view. When I start to drag the element after zooming though, it stutters at the start of dragging, which I'm assuming is due to the transform-origin being at a different spot now? I'm not totally sure. Here's my code


inputElement = document.getElementById("input");
inputElement.addEventListener("change", handleFiles, false);
canvas1 = document.getElementById('canvas1');
ctx1 = canvas1.getContext('2d');

function handleFiles(val) {
  console.log(val)
}
const scrollBox = document.getElementById('scroll-box');
canvas1.style.transformOrigin = 'center center';

const zoomSlider = document.getElementById('zoomSlider');
let scale = 1;
let startX = 0;
let startY = 0;
let translateX = 0;
let translateY = 0;
let isDragging = false;
let lastX = 0;
let lastY = 0;


scrollBox.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
  isDragging = true;
  startX = e.clientX;
  startY = e.clientY;
  scrollBox.style.cursor = 'grabbing';
});

scrollBox.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
  if (isDragging) {
    const deltaX = (e.clientX - startX) / scale;
    const deltaY = (e.clientY - startY) / scale;
    translateX += deltaX;
    translateY += deltaY;
    startX = e.clientX;
    startY = e.clientY;
    applyTransform();
  }
});

scrollBox.addEventListener('mouseup', (e) => {
  isDragging = false;
  lastX = startX;
  lastY = startY;
  scrollBox.style.cursor = 'grab';
});

scrollBox.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
  isDragging = false;
  scrollBox.style.cursor = 'grab';
});

zoomSlider.addEventListener('input', (e) => {

  scale = Math.max(((e.target.value) / 100) * 2, 0.02);

  applyTransform();
});

function applyTransform() {
  canvas1.style.transformOrigin = `${lastX / 2}px ${lastY}px`;

  document.getElementById('canvas1').style.transform = `scale(${scale}, ${scale}) translate(${translateX}px, ${translateY}px)`;

}
<input type="text" id="input">
<canvas id="canvas1">
<div id="scroll-box"></div>
<div id="zoomSlider"></div>



I tried to adjust the "translateX" and "translateY" variables while zooming to make it stay in the middle, but I was unable to make that work.

The solution is to move
canvas1.style.transformOrigin = `${lastX / 2}px ${lastY}px`;

into the zoom input event handler.
